# How to save file type custom option field value when you add a product in your cart?

Tags: custom-options

I have been trying to create add to cart options programmatically. It's working well when i add a simple value but i cannot add any file type like any image.

I used this code to add it with order cart item.

```
$additionalOptions = array(array(
            'code' => 'lmc_custom_thread',
            'label' => 'Thread Color',
            'value' => "radhagobindwa Das",
            'print_value' => "radhagobindwa Das",
            'option_id' => "test",
            'option_type' => "file",
            'custom_view' => '',
            'image_path' =>  '/media/'."j2t_image_small.png",
        ));

        $item->addOption(array(
            'code' => 'additional_options',
            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
        ));
```

It's shows only value ["radhagobindwa Das"] and I want to show this image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to get this value to display in cart , review sections.

You can able to retrieve the additional_options from cart renderer file using

```
$additionalOptions = $_item->getOptionByCode('additional_options'); 
$additional_options = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());

//or by using 

 $additional_options = $_item->getProductOptions();
```

Print it and see your image stored there. From here you can show the uploaded image src.